# Efficient Code Design for Pattern Search Using a Singleton Pattern

Tags: design, search, singleton, pattern-matching

I am having difficulty figuring out an efficient (thread-safe) code design for the following problem. I have been at it for some time now and would really appreciate some advice and input on how best to approach this.

I am basically searching for various patterns inside a data set. I would like to have one "master" class. I call this class Patterns. I am thinking of making this class a singleton pattern or a static class. I wish to have only one instance of this master class. I am coding this class as a singleton pattern
(pattern by Jon Skeet) at this time.

```
 public sealed class Patterns
 {
      private Patterns()
      {}

      public static Patterns Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

      private class Nested
      {
           // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
           // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
           static Nested()
           {
                // ...  create a list to hold data for internal use
                List<Point> Data = new List<Point>();
           }

           internal static readonly Patterns instance = new Patterns();
      }
 }
```

I have chosen a singleton pattern because:

1. I want the singleton to hold nested classes; one class for each pattern.
2. I want these nested classes to be instance classes (i.e. not static)
3. I would like the singleton to instantiate the nested classes, perhaps using a factory pattern, as needed.

I am not sure whether my reasoning here is correct so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Now I plan to add the various pattern classes as nested classes because patterns do not make sense outside the master Pattern class. Also, IPattern is an interface for the patterns.

```
 public sealed class Patterns
 {
      private Patterns()
      {}

      public static Patterns Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

      private class Nested
      {
           // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
           // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
           static Nested()
           {
                // ...  create a list to hold data for internal use
                static List<Point> Data = new List<Point>();

                // ... indices to track occurences of each pattern
                static int AIndex = 0;
                static int BIndex = 0;
                static int CIndex = 0;
           }

           internal static readonly Patterns instance = new Patterns();
      }

      // ... Methods

      public bool SearchForPattern(Point dataPoint)
      {
           // ... add data to list
           Data.Add(dataPoint);
      }

      // ... nested pattern classes

      class PatternA : IPattern
      {
           static int = some integer
           static double[] arr = new double[];

           // ... do some work
      }

      class PatternB : IPattern
      {
           // ... do some work
      }

      class PatternC : IPattern
      {
           // ... do some work
      }
 }
```

The List Data is static because I want the data to be retained throughout the lifetime of the application. Same for the static fields in the nested classes.

This is where I now begin to really get lost. In the method SearchForPattern(Point dataPoint) I would like to do the following:

```
      public bool SearchForPattern(Point dataPoint)
      {
           // ... add data to list
           Data.Add(dataPoint);

           bool haveA = PatternA.SearchForA();
           if (haveA)
           {
                PatternA a1 = new PatternA();     // the number after a will change as other A patterns are found; as per AIndex value
                AIndex++;
           }

                ... and so on for other patterns
      }
```

So here are my questions. Please note that I am fairly new to C# and I am trying to learn.

1. Is this the best (i.e. most computationally efficient) approach to take with this problem? If not, can you please suggest an alternative approach?
2. I do not know how to incorporate the factory pattern for the instantiation of the nested pattern classes. Should this be done? If so, can you suggest how?
3. Am I missing anything here that I need to consider but have not considered so far?

Comment: singleton is a bad idea, it is ever not needed or will lead to trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this is not helpful to me. You do not say why in my case and what would be an alternative. Furthermore, there are many arguments on the net that singletons are useful.

Comment: The most important reason — Singleton violates “single responsibility principle”: singleton is a class and its factory rolled into one.  The less important reason — Singleton in nearly impossible to implement, at there is almost always a way around it.

Comment: Please note comments are not answers, therefore they do not answer the question.

Comment: I don't have an answer, except to say I think you may be on the wrong path. singleton is considered harmful, god/master class is considered harmful, making a library of patterns is considered harmful: Some patterns can be libryfied in some languages, but in general they can not. Pattern seek to go beyond libraries. There are reusable ideas, where as libraries are reusable code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate it. Nonetheless, I need to search for these patterns. So what might be a better alternative? I am open to any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you think you need a singleton in the first place. If thread safety is a concern, why not just instantiate an independent, separate pattern searching instance for each thread? This is as thread safe as it gets

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I mentioned, I am still learning. I am not sure that I do need a singleton but I have explained my reasoning in the question posed. I do not want multiple instances of the Pattern class, but I need multiple instances of the various nested classes. Not sure I can have instance classes with instance methods inside a static class. I have thought about this for some time. I am not sure what the best approach is so I am asking here.

Comment: `I am not sure that I do need a singleton` - if so, I wouldn't use it. When in doubt, err on the safe side. I just posted an answer trying to tackle your doubts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have chosen a singleton pattern because:
>
> 1. I want the singleton to hold nested classes; one class for each pattern.

This doesn't require a singleton, or a static class. You could have

```
public class Patterns // non-static
{
    public class PatternA : IPattern { }
    public class PatternB : IPattern { }
}
```

and you'd be able to use it as a bag for your pattern definitions, and to instantiate instances of `PatternA` and `PatternB` just the same.

> 2. I want these nested classes to be instance classes (i.e. not static)

This again has nothing to do with using a singleton (see above).

> 3. I would like the singleton to instantiate the nested classes, perhaps using a factory pattern, as needed.

Once again, no singleton necessary. You could have a non-static pattern factory:

```
public class PatternsFactory
{
    public IEnumerable<IPattern> CreatePatterns()
    {
        return new List<IPattern> 
        {
            new Patterns.PatternA(), 
            new Patterns.PatternB()
        };
    }
}
```

> Now I plan to add the various pattern classes as nested classes
>   because patterns do not make sense outside the master Pattern class.

And why not? That's what [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) are for. Using an umbrella class as a bag for class definitions looks like reinventing the wheel to me. Namespaces serve this very purpose: grouping related classes together. Why bounce them out of their only job?

If patterns may make no sense outside the `Patterns` namespace, mark them as `internal`, that is invisible from outside the namespace. You might want to keep `IPattern` itself public for testing purposes, though (about this in a while).

> Am I missing anything here that I need to consider but have not considered so far?

One of the reasons that the use of statics is frowned upon is **testability**. How would you write a suite of unit tests for your pattern matching functionality? You can't create a mock pattern, because you cannot inject another pattern into your `Pattern` class. Heck, you can't even subclass it, since you made it `sealed`.

You're forcing all patterns to save their matches in a static `Data` object, which means that testing would require wiping it clean after every test. And again, there is no way to override it, other than rewriting the thing.

More reading on the subject:

- [Singletons are pathological liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)
- [Static methods are death to testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/)

Another concern is **extensibility**. What happens every time you want to add another pattern? You need to edit your `Patterns` class and put another implementation in there. You need to edit code of `SearchForPattern` to add all these nice

```
if (haveN) PatternN n = new PatternN();
```

That's inflexible and hard to maintain. The [open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) states that code should be open for extension, and your approach rules this out.

> If not, can you please suggest an alternative approach?

I would ditch singletons, because I see no purpose of using them. I'd create a `PatternFactory`, capable of returning a set of all supported `IPattern` objects, and instantiate the factory wherever I would need it (it's stateless anyway).

As for the data - pattern matches - that you want to retain throughout the lifetime of the application (`List Data is static because I want the data to be retained throughout the lifetime of the application`), well, you can make it static, although that's not the only possible way of tying its lifecycle to the one of the application.

But why be hellbent on placing it in the same class object where all the patterns are defined?? Knowing all supported patterns, and persisting all pattern matches that we detected somewhere are not the same responsibility at all (see [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). This design choice smells of the [God object antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

> Is this the best (i.e. most computationally efficient) approach to take with this problem?

What is computationally expensive here is the pattern matching itself, for non-trivial amounts of data at least. Therefore the cost of creating instances as opposed to using a static class is negligible, so as far as OOP design goes, I wouldn't expect performance to be affected.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and thoughtful answer Konrad. It is interesting that currently I have the various pattern classes inside a namespace. I was simply looking for a way to centralize the patterns and searching for them. You have given me much to think about. Thank you.

Comment: @Zeos happy to hear this, glad I could help

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and thoughtful answer Konrad. It is interesting that currently I have the various pattern classes inside a namespace. I was simply looking for a way to centralize the patterns and searching for them. You have given me much to think about; I clearly need to learn more about code design. Thank you. Also, can you please elaborate on your second last paragraph? What is the other way to static?

Comment: Also, I understand your last paragraph to mean that I should have one object for detecting the patterns and another one for persisting them throughout the lifecycle of the application. Can you suggest which objects? Do you mean a Dictionary to hold the patterns found? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you need to keep track of which matches were detected by which  pattern, then yes you could have a `Dictionary` with various `IPattern` as keys, or maybe even a dedicated `PatternMatch` class (consisting of an `IPattern` and a collection of matches), which could be more convenient in the long run - see http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Prefer_Domain-Specific_Types_to_Primitive_Types

The recommended choice would depend on the broader context. The important thing is that these solutions do not require knowing a precise, finite list of available patterns beforehand.

Comment: Thank you Konrad. You also mentioned that statics are frowned upon. What is the other way to persist data throughout the lifetime of the application? Also, any suggestions for a good primer on code design? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what exact application it is, but eg. in WPF you subclass the `Application` object and you could keep your data in `MyApp`, see `http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-wpf-application-class-overview-and-gotcha/` - `MyApp` is not static, but you have a guarantee that there's only ever going to be one instance of it, and that it will live throughout the entire application session (because it **is** the application).

Comment: Code design is a very broad subject, but I think your mindset is that you wish to design a program like a monument. However since the only permanent thing is change (even if it's a personal project, if you care about the design at all, it's likely not a throw-away single-use one), you should design for change instead. Also, don't use a design pattern just for the sake of doing so  (if you are not sure whether you should). This is known as cargo-cult programming. The use of design pattern should answer a specific need, not be a goal in its own right :)

Comment: You're welcome. As far as books are concerned, I'd start with "Clean Code" (by Robert C. Martin) before diving into design patterns :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you took with your thoughtful and detailed answers. They were very instructive and helpful - really showed me how much more I have to learn. :) Based on this discussion, what would you suggest as an effective approach to this problem to get me started? I would really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: `Patterns` namespace, public `IPattern` and a number of specific patterns as stand-alone classes. `PatternsFactory` creating a collection of all currently supported patterns. `PatternMatch` class with a readonly `IPattern` field (set in the constructor once and immutable after that) and a collection of data entries that satisfied the specific pattern. `MatchFinder`, taking a collection of `Pattern`s as an input and spitting out a collection of identified `PatternMatch`es.

Comment: Store the `PatternMatch` objects from the output in some sort of a context object, whose life is maintained by putting it in `MyApp` or some sort of its equivalent for the given platform, the use of a static object is not out of question but should be done sparringly. Write unit test using an arbitrary, dummy `Pattern` created solely for this test (the ability to do this is by itself a litmus test of a good architecture). This is a sample approach not a holy grail of course

Comment: Thank you very much for a great starting point.I will get started on this. If it is OK with you, is there any way I could pass some ideas by you as I develop them?

Comment: @Zeos any time you have a specific question, post it here please. That's what the forum is for, and as much as everyone can share their insights with you, there's plenty of other readers who may benefit from it. I have learned tremendously by confronting my ideas with the experience shared by others on StackExchange. General software design brainstorming here, more specific problems on http://stackoverflow.com/, and there is also http://codereview.stackexchange.com for polishing your solution once you got it thought through and working.

Comment: I did not know this Konrad. Once again, thank you for your generosity and very thoughtful advice. I will now work on the design and as I refine it, I will post it here for comments/advice/suggestions.